# Save data from a php page into 2 sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good day!I really need your help guys. Can someone teach me what statements I need to save data into 2 tables. I have 2 tables namely sales and sales_item. The relationship bet. them is the srfno where in sales table it is the PK, so in sales_item table it is the FK. My php form has srfno, date, clientid, clientname, address, contactperson, contactno, returnreason, explanation, refno; these data should be saved in sales table which I already did and it's working brilliantly. My problem now is that qty, serial, desc also include in the form but these should be saved in sales_item table. When I execute the page, it saves the data in sales table and the qty, serial and desc can't save to sales_item table and it didn't get the srfno from sales table.

here's my code for saving qty, serial and desc to sales_item table which is being ignored by my sql statement when saving.

```
$retitem= "Select `srfno` from sales_item"; 
        $psql= mysql_query($retitem,$con);  
        $reti = mysql_num_rows($psql);
        $reti = $reti + 1;
            while($return = mysql_fetch_assoc($psql))
            {
                if(isset($return['srfno']))
                {
                    $srfno=$return['srfno'];
                }

            }
        $addretex="Insert into `sales_item` (`sitemid`,`srfno`, `retqty`, `retdesc`,`retserial`, `exqty`, `exdesc`,`exserial`,)
                     VALUES (' ','$srfno', '$qty', '$desc', '$serialno', ' ', ' ', ' ')";
        $ret=mysql_query($addretex);
```

Answer (score 0):

easily you can use LAST_INSERT_ID to insert your last 3 values into table sales_item with related sales id.

```
  INSERT INTO sales (srfno,date,clientid,clientname,address,contactperson,contactno, returnreason,explanation,refno)
  VALUES('value1', 'value2','','',...);
  INSERT INTO sales_item (sales_id,qty,serial,desc) //sales_id is foreign key came from sales table and its value will be insert automatically by using LAST_INSERT_ID.
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'value_1', 'value_2','value_3');
```

Comment: how will I initialize it? my first query was put in a variable. How about the second statement?

Answer (score 0):

Before Inserting into 'sales_item', you need to check whether $srfno has valid value using

echo "srfno=".$srfno;exit;

if not, you can easily get value of $srfno after inserting into sales table, just do following after inserting into sales table

$srfno=mysql_insert_id();

You can also check error of insert query of sales_item by mysql_error function

mysql_query($addretex) or die("$addretex ".mysql_error());